# Variant allele frequency versus population frequency

Tags: allele-frequency, gnomad

In gnomAD related article

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9160216/#:~:text=Allele%20frequency%20is%20calculated%20by,can%20differ%20substantially%20between%20positions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9160216/#:%7E:text=Allele%20frequency%20is%20calculated%20by,can%20differ%20substantially%20between%20positions)

I road this section

> Allele frequency is calculated by dividing allele count by allele
> number, hence, allele frequency represents the frequency of
> confidently sequenced haplotypes that carry the allele in question
> (because coverage and sequencing quality varies across the genome, the
> allele number can differ substantially between positions). Allele
> frequency is not equivalent to the percentage of individuals that
> carry the allele, but is a suitable value for expressing the frequency
> of a variant in the general population. The number of individuals
> carrying a variant will depend on the number of heterozygous and
> homozygous individuals but can be calculated from the data provided in
> the variant table.

Does this mean, for getting the frequency of each allele in gnomAD, one could use `Allele frequency (AF)` column or must calculate population frequency?

Comment: What VCF fields are you comparing? I see the gnomAD has the overall `AF` field and various `AF` fields calculated by sample subset.

Comment: How did you subset gnomAD VCF to non-finnish samples only?

Comment: You might find gnomAD's non-cancer AF fields useful. I'll try to decipher the formula. `AN/2` is the number of samples (assuming all samples are diploid). `AC - num_homo` gives you `2*(num(hets))`. Dividing this by number of samples gives you frequency of samples with at least one ALT allele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gnomAD provides a global Allele Frequency as well as AF values for most subsets. gnomAD does not provide individual genotypes (as far as I know), so calculating custom AF for non-precomputed subsets might not be possible.

Since you're interested in the NFE (non-Finnish European) sub-population, the `nfe_*_AF` fields might be of interest to you.

---

As far as calculating the fraction of non-WT samples from `num_homozygous_samples`, `AC`, and `AN` goes, your formula seems spot on. Here's my deconstruction of the formula:

Your formula is: `(AC - num_homozygous_samples)/(AN / 2))`

`AN/2` is the number of samples (assuming all samples are diploid). `AC - num_homo` gives you `2 * num_hets`. Dividing this by number of samples gives you frequency of samples with at least one ALT allele.

For example, let's take a dataset of 200 diploid samples where 100 are WT, 75 are het and 25 are hom-alt for a biallelic variant.

Since there are 200 diploid samples, `AN` is 400.

`AC` for the ALT allele is `(75 * 1) + (25 * 2) = 125`.

Since 100 are WT, it is known that fraction of samples with mutation = `1 - (100/200) = 0.5`. This number can be arrived using your formula:

```
(AC - num_homozygous_samples) / (AN/2)
 = ((125 - 25) / (400/2))
 = 100 / 200
 = 0.5
```